# foreach not working when FOR loop contains seq

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to parallel process a simulation and my function has a for loop with sequence that shows start, finish and increment. When I convert FOR in to foreach I see a syntax error. A simplified example is below.Appreciate any input to parallel process this code.

```
fn_foreach <- function(){ 
 for(i in seq(0.01,0.1,0.01)) #i range 0.01-0.1 increments by 0.01 
 { 
 # print(paste("t =", i))
 dots <- sqrt(i)} 
 return(dots)
 }

 x2 <- fn_foreach()
```

Comment: Where is the code that changes `for` to `foreach` ?

Comment: Oliver had posted the code with foreach. The 'in' was giving trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a misunderstanding of `foreach`. `foreach` is a utility provided by the `foreach` package.

```
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i = seq(0.01, 0.1, 0.01)) %dopar% {
  sqrt(i)
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the error is foreach does not like 'in' i get the following error but i fixed it by creating a vector for seq(0.01, 0.1, 0.01). Error: unexpected 'in' in "foreach(i in"
>   sqrt(i)
Error: object 'i' not found.

Comment: library(foreach)
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i = seq(0.01, 0.1, 0.01)) %dopar% {
  sqrt(i)
}
stopCluster(cl)